# Running a job on multiple nodes of a GridEngine cluster

Tags: python, sungridengine, qsub

I have access to a 128-core cluster on which I would like to run a parallelised job. The cluster uses Sun GridEngine and my program is written to run using Parallel Python, numpy, scipy on Python 2.5.8. Running the job on a single node (4-cores) yields an ~3.5x improvement over a single core. I would now like to take this to the next level and split the job across ~4 nodes. My `qsub` script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# The name of the job, can be whatever makes sense to you
#$ -N jobname

# The job should be placed into the queue 'all.q'.
#$ -q all.q

# Redirect output stream to this file.
#$ -o jobname_output.dat

# Redirect error stream to this file.

#$ -e jobname_error.dat

# The batchsystem should use the current directory as working directory.
# Both files will be placed in the current
# directory. The batchsystem assumes to find the executable in this directory.
#$ -cwd

# request Bourne shell as shell for job.
#$ -S /bin/sh

# print date and time
date

# spython is the server's version of Python 2.5. Using python instead of spython causes the program to run in python 2.3
spython programname.py

# print date and time again
date
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question? People should really leave a comment if they have negative feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to include the Grid Engine option `-np 16` either in your script like this:

```
# Use 16 processors
#$ -np 16
```

or on the command line when you submit the script.  Or, for more permanent arrangements, use an `.sge_request` file.

On all the GE installations I've ever used this will give you 16 processors (or processor cores these days) on as few nodes as necessary, so if your nodes have 4 cores you'll get 4 nodes, if they have 8 2 and so on.  To place the job on, say 2 cores on 8 nodes (which you might want to do if you need a lot of memory for each process) is a little more complicated and you should consult your support team.

Comment: Adding `~$ -np 8` comes up with an error saying `Unable to read script file because of error: ERROR! invalid option argument "-np"`. I now have a Python-only solution for this, but it would be nice to have another option.

Comment: @Chinmay Kanchi: add #$ -np 16, not ~$ -np 16

Comment: Yes, that is what I had done. Missed out the `#` in the comment. Cheers.